# SFPx consuming Dynamics 365 CRM API

Tags: spfx, dataverse

I’m trying to connect to dataverse via an app registration in Azure AD but I’m always receiving HTTP 401 responses when I try to get data via the AadHttpClient object (referencing the custom app client id) in SPFx project.

Has something been changed on how to connect to dataverse?

I’ve enabled the ‘oauth2AllowImplicitFlow’ option in the app registration manifest and granted user_impersontate permission on Dynamics CRM. Also the webApiPermissionRequests were added to the package-solution.json file in the spfx project.